# BlenderKit Traceback Fix? (Blender 2.9)

Tags: python, add-on

I am trying to use the BlenderKit addon, and I keep getting this Traceback error. How do I fix this? Cuz the BlenderKit Addon used to work before but now this error keeps popping up. (This Version of Blender is 2.9)

[image]